# $this->db->where how to use it?

Tags: database, codeigniter

In this code, I want to select the records from database only where the employee_id_open and the employee_id_close is the same and is same to a variable `$employee_id`

```
$employee_id = 1;
$between = 'between ' . $this->db->escape($this->params['start_date'] . ' 00:00:00').' and ' . $this->db->escape($this->params['end_date'] . ' 23:59:59');
        $this->db->select("registers.name as register_name, open_person.first_name as open_first_name, open_person.last_name as open_last_name,open_person.hourly_salary as hourly_salary, close_person.first_name as close_first_name, close_person.last_name as close_last_name, register_log.*, (register_log.close_amount - register_log.open_amount - register_log.cash_sales_amount) as difference");
        $this->db->from('register_log as register_log');
        $this->db->join('people as open_person', 'register_log.employee_id_open=open_person.person_id');
        $this->db->join('people as close_person', 'register_log.employee_id_close=close_person.person_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('registers', 'registers.register_id = register_log.register_id');
        //------My modification - but this is not working. no records are selected with this query
        $this->db->where('open_person.person_id ', 'close_person.person_id');
        // I also tried this>>>  $this->db->where('open_person.person_id = ', 'close_person.person_id');
        //------/ My modifcation
        $this->db->where('register_log.shift_start ' . $between);
        $this->db->where('register_log.deleted ', 0);
        $this->db->where('registers.location_id', $location_id);
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Many Thanks

Comment: remember they way you used left join is useless if you use where condition on that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can dump the last query sql  statement using $this->db->last_query().

Comment: Thank you! It helps me to find the problem, and Now I have fixed it...
Thanks a lot!